# how to pass required variable in class using object manager magento2

Tags: magento2, object-manager

I have a class

```
$class = new Abc\Cde\Efg('variable');
```

how can i implement this using object manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$class = $objectManager->create(Abc\Cde\Efg);
```

The variable value is required. Right now i have only one option to use new. but i dont want to use new keyword in magento2

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
$class = $objectManager->create('Abc\Cde\Efg', ['Variable']);
```

Comment: not working, it is still throwing error. Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument